# Moving from Snaps to Apt (home desktop situation)

Tags: apt, snap, ubuntu-core

While I understand that developers maintaining versions appreciate snap functionality, home users probably won't. People install Ubuntu for home use, as a replacement of other OSs, one of the reasons might be the low-resource demand. Since I installed Ubuntu 20.04, my disk (particularly root partition) is permanently full. The offending directory being /var/lib/snapd/snaps. I have already reduced snap retention to 2 (one current, one recent), but still, the same issue with excess space usage. This may actually frustrate "regular users" who want foremost to use their PC for some work, not to play with tools and utilities and spend hours with tweaking the settings. I am talking about opt-in situation than this enforced opt-out in regards of snap.

I noticed that some preinstalled tools: vlc, clementine, gimp, gnome, but also zoom or skype - are installed as snaps.

I would appreciate at least one easy to find **webpage/procedure** for "undemanding home users" **explaining how to easily migrate from snap installs of these (as many as possible) tools to regular apt**. Or do I have to manually "snap remove" and then "apt install" for every single one? Any risk of breaking dependencies on the way?

What about things like core, gnome, eventually snapstore, snapd -> am I forced to keep them as snaps, tumorizing my disk space?

This may be a great utility for a specific use, but distributing it as a default was a bad idea imho.

Comment: I have removed snapd entirely along with all the garbage it carries. Just use apt as regular, everything works like before.